# Python - Trying to using a "for" to create a set and then apply another for that will interate and generate a dict. But its is returning "error"

Tags: python, for-loop, set, classification, nltk

I am trying to using a *"for"* to create a *set* and then apply another *for* that will interate and generate a *dict*. But its is returning "error"

**Some important details:**

`test_tabela` is a list

```
[['read', 'lost'],
 ['char', 'jonah', 'padra'],
 ['angul', 'shock', 'jonah'],
 ['angul', 'enough']]
```

`words_base` is a dict keys

```
dict_keys(['angul', 'enough', 'equip', 'padra', 'shock', 'padro', 'love'])
```

`classifier_text` is a NLKT trained classifier that must classify "text_test" based in Naive Bayes.

`new1` must be included on a new list that will be the classes list for each element on `test_tabela`. Something like:

```
newlist.append(new1)
```

**The code that I am trying**

```
for i in test_tabela:
    doc_test = set(teste_tabela[i])
    text_test = {}
    for word in words_base:
        text_test['%s' % word] = (word in doc_test)
        new1 = (classifier_text(text_test))
```

but its returning error:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list

I really dont know what is wrong. When I try to create the *set* manually it works, like:

```
doc_test = set(test_tabela[3])
```

Yes. I am beginner.

Comment: In `set(teste_tabela[i])` -- `i` is an element of `test_tabela`, not an index. You just want `set(i)`

Comment: You don't need formatting `text_test['%s' % word]`. `word` is a string, so you can just use `text_test[word]`

Comment: You're confusing the way `for-in` works in dictionaries and lists. Dictionaries loop over keys, lists loop over values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`i` is an element of `tested_tabela`, because of that, change

```
doc_test = set(teste_tabela[i])
```

to

```
doc_test = set(i)
```